# How to read input values based on checkbox checked?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the input value inside of the table that is associated with the next checkbox? I just need to get only those input values whose checkbox is checked. Display the value as an innerHTML of div comma separated.

I can get all the input value but I am not able to apply the logic for the checkbox

I tried for all the input box values.

```
let olist = [...document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr')].map(row => {
                const childs = row.querySelectorAll("input");
                return {
                    oKey: parseInt(childs[1].value),
                }
            })
```

```js
function checkboxChecked(event) {
    let final = document.getElementById("final");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Checbox</td>
      <td>Key</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxChecked(event)"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value=1></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxChecked(event)"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value=2></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxChecked(event)"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value=3></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="final"></div>
```

Comment: First thing, change ```getElementByID``` to ```getElementById```, change ```<input type="numeric"``` to ```<input type="number"``` and please change ```checbocChecked``` to ```checkboxChecked```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Array.prototype.map()` function to create an array with transformed values. That's fine. But you want to include only values where the corresponding checkbox is checked. You can do that by adding a call to the `Array.prototype.filter()` function.

There are multiple ways to do this. One of the easiest solutions would be to first call `map()` to create an array with items containing the checkbox values and the corresponding number values, then use `filter()` to create an array with only the checked items, and then use `map()` again to get an array with the resulting number values. Something like this:

```
let olist =
  [...document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr')]
    .map(row => {
      const children = row.querySelectorAll('input');
      return {
        checked: children[0].checked,
        value: parseInt(children[1].value)
      }
    })
    .filter(item => item.checked)
    .map(item => item.value)

document.getElementById('final').innerHTML = olist.join(', ')
```

Note that you can probably omit the `parseInt` call inside the first `map` callback function as well, because afterwards you are just concatenating those values into a string again.

**Edit**

An even shorter alternative would be something like this:

```
let olist =
  [...document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr')]
    .filter(row => row.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked)
    .map(row => row.querySelector('input[type=number]').value)

document.getElementById('final').innerHTML = olist.join(', ')
```

Comment: The shorter alternative one will fail if there two input box both of them are of type number. Anyways Thanks @Bart Hofland

Comment: That's correct. In that case, I would add different CSS classes to those input elements. Then you can specify those classes in the `querySelector` call instead of the attributes. The table row HTML might contain something like `<input type="number" class="value1">` and `<input type="number" class="value2">`, for example. The corresponding Javascript code to search for them would be `row.querySelector('input.value1')` and `row.querySelector('input.value2')`.

Comment: Thankyou so much @Bart Hofland, I had already used this

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkboxChecked(event) {
    let checkBox=event.path[0]
    let input=event.path[2].children[1].children[0]
    console.log(`Box Checked: ${checkBox.checked}\nValue: ${input.value}`)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Checbox</td>
      <td>Key</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxChecked(event)"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value=1></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxChecked(event)"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value=2></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxChecked(event)"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value=3></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="final"></div>
```